# Accepting packets only from specific IP

Tags: networking, router

I have *IP Camera* which is behind a *router* and it gets thousands of incoming packets from many IP's outside the country and this causes bad connection to the camera.

I am thinking of put a rule on the router to accept packets only from a specific IP.

Since I am not familiar with inner working of routers and a newbie in networking, do you have an idea if rejecting packets from all IP's but from one, will increase the connection to the camera?

Does the router need to accept the whole packet before rejecting it? Because if so, it seems it doesn't matter if I reject or accept them?

Comment: The router will check the header of the packet and then accept or reject it, it doesn't read the whole packet. If you specify a rule of incoming connections to just one, it will definitely speed things up, but I don't know if you will see dramatic changes. If you are using industrial routers (Cisco, Juniper) then access control lists is what you are looking for. For commercial routers I don't have a clue

Comment: You can alternatively create a VPN tunnell, that you will only know the VPN key.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your routers port is forwarded to the camera inside your LAN. 
It is NOT recommended to give direct access to a webcam from the internet just bear this in mind. There is a serious risk you that you will lose control of the device and leave all your devices in the network vulnerable. 
But if you do, then I suggest you use a firewall rule at the router. Please provide more technical information on your question so people can help you further. The router model will help.

Comment: Yes, I am port forwarding from the router to the IP Camera on a custom port, because I want to access it from outside. Let's abstract from the router model. I just need the idea - what is your suggestion of using firewall on the router? What rules do you suggest? And are IP Camera's more vulnerable than other devices in LAN?

Comment: The idea is, that there will be two firewall rules. One that rejects all traffic to this port and an other that accepts it from the IP address you want whitelisted.  Whether these are possible to be created depends on your router model. I would suggest @D.A solution. Rather than giving access to the camera from the internet directly, spend a few moments setting up a VPN for your client and you kill two birds with one stone. IP cameras are inherently more valuable to hackers because of the value of information they reveal, so attacks are more persistent